# Understanding segmentation fault in core dump on NULL pointer check

Tags: c++, c, segmentation-fault, coredump, null-pointer

I am having difficulty understanding how this segmentation fault is possible. The architecture of the machine is armv7l.

The core dump:

```
Dump of assembler code for function DLL_Disconnect:
   0x6cd3a460 <+0>:     15 4b   ldr     r3, [pc, #84]   ; (0x6cd3a4b8 <DLL_Disconnect+88>)
   0x6cd3a462 <+2>:     00 21   movs    r1, #0
   0x6cd3a464 <+4>:     15 4a   ldr     r2, [pc, #84]   ; (0x6cd3a4bc <DLL_Disconnect+92>)
   0x6cd3a466 <+6>:     30 b5   push    {r4, r5, lr}
   0x6cd3a468 <+8>:     83 b0   sub     sp, #12
   0x6cd3a46a <+10>:    7b 44   add     r3, pc
   0x6cd3a46c <+12>:    01 91   str     r1, [sp, #4]
   0x6cd3a46e <+14>:    04 46   mov     r4, r0
   0x6cd3a470 <+16>:    9d 58   ldr     r5, [r3, r2]
=> 0x6cd3a472 <+18>:    28 68   ldr     r0, [r5, #0]
   0x6cd3a474 <+20>:    c0 b1   cbz     r0, 0x6cd3a4a8 <DLL_Disconnect+72>
   0x6cd3a476 <+22>:    21 46   mov     r1, r4
...
   0x6cd3a4b6 <+86>:    00 bf   nop
   0x6cd3a4b8 <+88>:    96 b6 00 00     .word   0x0000b696 <- replaced from objdump, as gdb prints as instruction
   0x6cd3a4bc <+92>:    1c 02 00 00     .word   0x0000021c <- also replaced
```

The registers:

```
r0             0x0                 0
r1             0x0                 0
r2             0x21c               540
r3             0x6cd45b04          1825856260
r4             0x0                 0
r5             0x1dddc             122332
...
sp             0x62afeb40          0x62afeb40
lr             0x72a3091b          1923287323
pc             0x6cd3a472          0x6cd3a472 <DLL_Disconnect+18>
cpsr           0x600c0030          1611399216
fpscr          0x0                 0
```

The segmentation fault is caused when "ldr r0, [r5, #0]" tries to access the memory address pointed to by r5. In GDB I get a similar message when trying to access it in GDB:

```
(gdb) print *$r5
Cannot access memory at address 0x1dddc
```

However, all offending register values are calculated by static values. So I don't understand how the memory address is not accessible.

The source code is loaded and executed via a shared library using dlopen and dlsym:

```
CClient* gl_pClient = NULL;

extern "C" unsigned long DLL_Disconnect(unsigned long ulHandle)
{
    CProtocol* pCProtocol = NULL;

    unsigned long ulResult = ACTION_INTERNAL_ERROR;

    if (gl_pClient == NULL)
    {
        return ACTION_API_NOT_INITIALIZED;
    }
...
```

Comment: Try running your code through valgrind.  If you're mismanaging memory it will tell you where.

Comment: Is this compiled with optimizations on? If so, the error could be coming from anywhere in the function, as code might have been completely reorganized.

Comment: The code is compiled with GCC 4.9.2 and "-O3 -fdata-sections -ffunction-section -fPIC". But my point still stands: all values are calculated by static data.

Comment: @OP Find out which C-statement was the problematic machine instruction generated from. If compiled with option `-g`, command `objdump -dS objectmodule.o` might help.

Comment: @timonn I wouldn’t trust the debugger to be accurate there.  If you can reproduce the crash, I recommend rebuilding with some temporary printf’s sprinkled through the function so that you can see where the crash *really* occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The assembly code resolves the address of global variable `gl_pClient` using dll relocations, which are loaded using program-counter-relative addressing. Then the code loads from that address and crashes. It looks like the relocations got corrupted, so that the resolved address is invalid.

There isn't much else can be said without a reproduction.

You may like to run your program under `valgrind` which may report memory corruption.

Comment: Thank you for the technical terms. DLL relocation and program-counter-relative addressing are not concepts I am too familiar with.

Comment: But why is the relocation table writable? Shouldn't it be written by the loader once and then be marked as readonly?

Comment: The core dump shows for "maintenance info sections": 

[147] 0x6cd45000->0x6cd46000 at 0x0a4e7000: load76 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS

which is the range for the value in register r3

Comment: @timonn Reloacations are resolved by the run-time linker, `ld.so` on Linux. It can resolve all relocations on load and could make them read-only, but by default the relocation resolution is delayed till the first access and that's why relocations have read/write access. Windows may do it differently.